# Short Story: Group of people with powers living together - a sentient radio, a woman with coercive powers, and someone who can fix anything

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, powers

In Asimov's magazine, in the late 1980s or early 1990s, I recall a story about a group of people with odd powers or conditions who live together in an apartment.  The leader is a woman who has "the voice of command" - she can tell people to do things and won't be refused.  She generally abstains because using the power is addictive, and she rapidly spirals into very bad behavior (the TV series "Alphas" used a similar notion much later).  One of the persons in the household is a sentient radio.  I think the plot involves someone coming into the household and disrupting it; at one point, at the newcomers's suggestion, the woman with the voice of command steals from a nearby grocery store cashier, and is later cruel to the radio (I think).  There's a whimsical air to the story, I think. There's another character with exceptional repair skills (repairing things by simply touching them) - he might be responsible for the fact that the radio is now sentient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except that it's the new lodger Steven who controls people this sounds like "[A Place to Stay for a Little While](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42554)" (1986) by Jim Aikin.  As you suggest, it was published in *Asimov's*, June 1986, and reprinted in DAW's *The Year's Best Fantasy Stories: 13* (1987).

A talking radio:

> "I can't cope," Cynthia Lutz said to the radio. "I simply cannot cope."
>
> "Oh, come on," the radio said. It was a wooden table model that dated from about 1933. "Things aren't that bad. Things have been this bad before."
>
> "When?" Cynthia snapped.
>
> "Well, they must have been, some time or other," the radio said evasively. "How would I know? My memory isn't worth a damn. What do you expect from vacuum tubes?"

Steven explains his power:

> He swallowed with an effort. "I control people."
>
> A cold lump congealed at her stomach, and her scalp prickled. She looked at him silently, measuring him. This one could be dangerous.
>
> "I don't do it very often. I try not to."
>
> "Why try not to?"
>
> "I start to like it. It feels good. Like a drug."
>
> "So you try not to."
>
> "It's been four months."
>
> "When you say you control people, what do you mean?"
>
> "I control them, that's all. I give them orders, in my head, in a certain way, and they do whatever I say. They don't have any choice."

The radio suggests stealing food:

> "Pardon me for interrupting," the radio said, "but couldn't you work out a plan whereby Mrs. Simpston or Mr. Reeves could distract a grocery clerk while the rest of you take things off the shelves and put them in your pockets?"

Which they do with Steven convincing a cashier that they've paid for the food they take.

A previous boarder had "fixed" the radio:

> "Tell me about the radio."
>
> "Well, it's a nice old radio. I'm fond of it, even if it doesn't have much to say."
>
> "It just wandered in, the way I did?"
>
> "Not exactly. We've had maybe two dozen different people staying with us at one time or another. For a while there was this nice old guy — a farm hand from Missouri, he could barely read or write — who did things to machines. He never touched them; all he did was stare at them."
>
> "You mean he could fix things that were broken?"
>
> "It wasn't quite that simple. What things did after he got done with them was never exactly what they’d done before. The trouble was, he couldn't control it. He never knew ahead of time what would happen. Anyway, somebody had given us an old radio that didn't work, and I asked him if he couldn't see about fixing it up somehow. He was tickled pink when it started to talk — said he'd never gotten anything to do something like that before."

There's a man who fixes the holes in the world, a man who fades in and out of reality and can walk through walls, a young woman who starts to become the person people expect her to be, an old woman who sees a completely different reality from the rest...

Comment: That's clearly it - thanks!